# How to create build pipeline in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli, jenkins-job-dsl

How to create build pipeline view in Jenkins using Jenkins CLI or through scripting? I would prefer CLI if possible.

Right now I create a Bunch of jobs including downstream. So would prefer a way to automate pipeline view.

Answer (score 3):

Step 1: For creating a build pipeline, First create a set of jobs.
[image: Pipeline jobs]

Step 2: Now create a build pipeline view and in the configure section add the first job that you want to run in the pipeline

[image: New pipe line view]

Step 3:Now for every job, add a post build action, which can be modified many ways, for example manual trigger or automatic trigger on successful of the build.

[image: downstream projects]

step 4: Once all the downstream jobs are configured, just build the p1 job. and go to the new pipeline view that you have created.

[image]

Note: You won't see a pipeline untill first job is started. In this example, after p1 job is started you will start seeing a pipeline

Answer (score 0):

Use [BUILD FLOW](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin) plugin, in which you can use simple DSL scripts.

By using this plugin you can build both pipeline & parallel jobs

Comment: thx, I can build pipeline dynamically using jenkins cli, but after creating this pipeline...would like to create a new pipeline view and associate the parent job dynamically through scripting as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Job DSL Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin) to define a [Build Pipeline View](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/buildPipelineView) and any jobs for the pipeline.

If you want to run the DSL from CLI, you can checkout the [REST API Runner](https://github.com/sheehan/job-dsl-gradle-example#rest-api-runner).

Comment: Could you help me with some example script on how to create a pipeline view through scripting.